# What exactly is caching and how do I add it to an app I have on heroku?

Tags: flask

I have a data science type application where I am getting public information from FPDS and SAM gov't website. The site is currently on Heroku.

I would like cache views so if a person is researching more than one company they can quickly go back to earlier pages without having to fetch the results from the database every time.

Based on my limited knowledge that is what cashing does?

Second, I am looking at [flash-caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) and it doesn't appear to be that difficult to implement to the route's I would like to cache.

Now the question is on Heroku, you wouldn't use `simplecashe` would you? Would you use a different cache strategy? From the docs, the `CASHE_TYPE` can be `simple`, `redis`, `memcached` and several more. On Heroku would I need to store the cache on something like Redis or can I store it in memory? Ideally, to get everything up and running I would like the cache to be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer to your question. Caching can be a number of techniques on client and server side to achieve a goal of reduced traffic, network transport, or speed.

I'll focus on one aspect from what you are asking: a redis integration with flask to achieve faster response from a flask app environment. Redis is 'blindingly' fast, imo, as an in-memory database. When I have many users asking for the same view (typically a report-style display), I can interrupt the view route to get the response from a named redis database, so that my flask server is not bound up in eternally regenerating the same contents, which in turn saves a good few cycles of the main back-end database. Of course, if the contents of that view/report change, I have to separately take care of that. Most importantly, Redis includes an expiry value for each entry, so one way of handling stale contents is to delete the redis contents ahead of the expiry time.

Let me know if you want sample code to demonstrate this.